# jQuery click anchor tag one by one using parent child

Tags: jquery, click, anchor, parent-child

I have a table grid that contains a short description along with a HTML anchor tag that has the text "read more".

I want to click one by one on the anchor tags using jquery that contain the text "read more".
for showing the rest of other text in table

```
<div class="description_short col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type a<a href="#" class="expand_text">... read more  </a></div>
```

```
<div class="description_short col-sm-12 col-xs-12">"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the gr<a href="#" class="expand_text">... read more  </a></div>
```

There are lots of div elements in the table. How to click `... read more` anchor tag and show only that div text using jQuery?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: but i want to loop through using anchor tag

Comment: that does not work  $("a.expand_text").click() it will show all the following div text afte r clicking

Comment: can you add your full html block of `show more`, its hard to identify what you are toggling

Comment: check full html block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('.readmore').on('click',function() {
  $(this).parent().find('p').addClass('showText');
});
```

```css
p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.showText {
  max-width: inherit !important;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt rem odit quis quaerat. In dolorem praesentium velit ea esse consequuntur cum fugit sequi voluptas ut possimus voluptatibus deserunt nisi eveniet!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem voluptates vel dolorum autem ex repudiandae iste quasi. Minima explicabo qui necessitatibus porro nihil aliquid deleniti ullam repudiandae dolores corrupti eaque.</p><a class='readmore'>Read more</a></div>

<div class="text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt rem odit quis quaerat. In dolorem praesentium velit ea esse consequuntur cum fugit sequi voluptas ut possimus voluptatibus deserunt nisi eveniet!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem voluptates vel dolorum autem ex repudiandae iste quasi. Minima explicabo qui necessitatibus porro nihil aliquid deleniti ullam repudiandae dolores corrupti eaque.</p><a class='readmore'>Read more</a></div>

<div class="text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt rem odit quis quaerat. In dolorem praesentium velit ea esse consequuntur cum fugit sequi voluptas ut possimus voluptatibus deserunt nisi eveniet!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem voluptates vel dolorum autem ex repudiandae iste quasi. Minima explicabo qui necessitatibus porro nihil aliquid deleniti ullam repudiandae dolores corrupti eaque.</p><a class='readmore'>Read more</a></div>

<div class="text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt rem odit quis quaerat. In dolorem praesentium velit ea esse consequuntur cum fugit sequi voluptas ut possimus voluptatibus deserunt nisi eveniet!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem voluptates vel dolorum autem ex repudiandae iste quasi. Minima explicabo qui necessitatibus porro nihil aliquid deleniti ullam repudiandae dolores corrupti eaque.</p><a class='readmore'>Read more</a></div>
```

Comment: This would be in my opinion; the cleanest alternative using jQuery. Upvoted.

Comment: @Wimanicesir wow, I *completely* read the question differently.  Shows what a badly  worded question it is.  e.g. *"click one by one on the anchor tags **using jquery**"* says to me to "**using jquery**, click on the anchors."  Have a +1 for managing to interpret the question.